# Broadcomm WIDCOMM A2DP Quality Adjustment

Tags: audio, bluetooth, a2dp

So I got a sweet pair of bluetooth A2DP headphones for a sweet, sweet price (Motorola A805, if you were wondering). They sound great paired with an iPhone.

However, when I pair with a computer using the latest and greatest WIDCOMM drivers, the quality is quite poor, almost un-listenable... clicking, popping, scratching. The remedy on one machine was using BlueSoleil, another bluetooth stack, as there is an adjustment for the Bitpool settings that allow you to jack the quality up. Sounds great. However, the bluetooth chipset in my other machine is not supported by BlueSoleil... so I'm stuck with the WIDCOMM stack.

So the question is... Is there an undocumented way to turn up the quality for A2DP in the WIDCOMM drivers?

first question on SU, usually lurking on SO.. =]

Answer (score 1):

Even bluesoleil does not get the best of the A2DP sound quality. I tried it, and it was pretty fustrating when I hear the same limitations on the sound quality.

I found this article:

http://soundexpert.org/news/-/blogs/bluetooth-audio-quality-a2dp

toshiba bluetooth stack allows you to set the sample rate - meaning the quality.
On 328kbps you get the best of it, which for me is like wired sound (I cannot get the difference). The only drawnback is that it can be quite tricky for the toshiba bluetooth stack to find an internal bluetooth device. I have a DELL INSPIRON 1520 and an BELKIN USB dongle. The DELL's bluetooth is not found but the BELKIN works fine. Give it a try.